# I understood/ 've understood/ understand the matter from one of your previous examples. No need to explain more

Tags: grammar

I have a situation like this:

> My friend: Can you help me with this?
>
> Me: Yes, You should do like this. And you can do another way like this
>
> My friend: Thanks, I get it.
>
> Me: I will give you another example to make you understand more.
>
> My friend: __________(*)________________No need to explain more.

(1) I **understood** the matter from one of your previous examples. No need to explain more.

=> My native friend advised using the simple past. He said this one s natural.

(2) I **'ve understood** the matter from one of your previous examples. No need to explain more.

=> I think that "'ve understood" is also good to use. I want to use the present perfect because I want to focus on the present result that now I understand.

(3) I **understand** the matter from one of your previous examples. No need to explain more

=> I think that this one is also good to use.

The thing I am concerned the most is that between the use of simple past and present perfect for this situation.
Could you please give me your opinion?

Comment: I  would use (3), because the friend's understanding continues into the present.

Comment: I actually heard my friend have used (1). Are there any problems with the simple past “understood “ here?

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic here. To be honest, your entire text is full of mistakes.

Comment: @Astralbee I already tried to correct some of the mistakes.

Comment: @Astralbee - I don't see that this is proofreading, since the OP has identified a single issue that's causing a problem.

Comment: I think a native speaker would say "Thank you, I understand it now." It doesn't feel so natural to say "I understood it from your first example", and perhaps it even sounds a little rude, as though you think they are wasting their time by offering further explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since understanding is a state that you are currently in, the simple present is the most idiomatic here:

> I understand the matter from one of your previous examples.

That said, speaking informally, you could just use the idiom:

> I got it.